# Out of bounds in array loop

Tags: java, arrays

Can anyone explain to me how this  `nums.length-2` works so that you would be able to use `i+1` and `i+2` in the loop

```
public boolean array123(int[] nums) {

    for (int i=0; i < nums.length-2; i++) {
        if (nums[i]==1 && nums[i+1]==2 && nums[i+2]==3) return true;
    }
return false;
}
```

Comment: Make a small array and work it out on a piece of paper! :)

Comment: Print the values you 'i' to confirm it, it will range from [0,nums.length -1] .

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this, and start some pen work.

things will be more clear.

Let say array is `int[] nums` as below.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can understand this thing by taking an example array.
Suppose you have an array [1,2,3,4] so now your length is 4 and loop condition is i

Answer (score -2):

Change the for loop condition to    i <= nums.length-2    instead of i < nums.length-2, it works!!

Comment: This does not work; the last value of i in the loop would be nums.length - 2, then you attempt to access index nums.length-2+2, ==nums.length, causing an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Furthermore, this does not answer the question, which was not asking for improvements to the code.